# What is the mode of inference for frequentist IPTW estimation in the causal inference context

Tags: causality, assumptions, weights

In Rubin 1990, Donald Rubin describes four different modes of statistical inference for causal effects:

1. Randomization-based tests of sharp-null hypotheses - in the tradition of Fisher, if you've got an unconfounded assignment mechanism combined with a sharp null hypothesis of no treatment effect, you compute the value of a test statistic in your sample and compare that to the sampling distribution of the test statistic under the null to get a p-value (which can also give you a confidence interval by inverting the null hypothesis test)
2. Randomization-based inference for sampling distributions of estimands (aka repeated sampling randomization-based inference) - in the tradition of Neyman for survey sampling, where you define an estimand of interest Q, select a statistic $\hat{Q}$ that is an unbiased estimator of the estimand, find a statistic $\hat{V}$ that is an unbiased estimator of the variance of $\hat{Q}$, assume the randomization distribution of $(Q - \hat{Q}) \sim N(0, \hat{V})$, and perform inference using that distribution (sometimes you assume a t-distribution instead of a normal distribution).
3. Bayesian inference (aka Bayesian model-based inference) - take the assignment mechanism from the potential outcomes framework, supplement it with a joint probability model $Pr(X,Y)$ (factored in such a way that $Pr(X,Y) = \int \prod_{i=1}^{N} f(X_i, Y_i | \theta) Pr(\theta) d\theta$, where $\theta$ is a parameter such that it's straightforward to compute the causal estimand Q as a function of $\theta$) for your covariates and outcome, specify the prior distribution of the parameter $Pr(\theta)$ and calculate the posterior distribution of the causal estimand of interest Q.
4. Superpopulation frequency inference (aka repeated-sampling model-based inference)- take the assignment mechanism and the probability model $\prod_{i=1}^{N} f(X_i, Y_i | \theta)$, but discard the prior distribution and draw frequency inferences about $\theta$ using tools of mathematical statistics like maximum likelihood, likelihood ratios, etc.

Suppose I am using an inverse probability of treatment weighted (IPTW) estimator to fit a marginal structural model to estimate the average treatment effect (ATE) of an active treatment relative to a control treatment using observational data. Let's make the usual assumptions needed to do this kind of inference (treatment version irrelevance, no interference, positivity, conditional exchangeability/no unmeasured confounders, no measurement error in X, correct specification of the nuisance model to estimate the weights, any missing data satisfy the stratified MCAR assumption).

If I want to do frequentist inference and get a 95% confidence interval for the ATE, am I appealing to inference mode 2 (repeated sampling randomization-based inference) or 4 (repeated sampling model-based inference)? Or is there some other argument used in this setting to justify variance estimation.

Rubin, Donald B. (1990). Formal modes of statistical inference for causal effects. *Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference.* 25. 279-292.